# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://[::1]:3000/api/requests/...' from from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, loopbackjs, loopback4

I have a project:

- Back-end use Loopback 4.
- Front-end use Angular.

About 3 days ago, it working well. But now it working.
This is error image:
[image]

I try cros setting on server:

```js
export async function main(options: ApplicationConfig = {
    rest: {
        cors: {
            origin: '*',
            methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
            preflightContinue: false,
            optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
            maxAge: 86400,
            credentials: true,
        },
    },
}) {
    const app = new ApartmentManagementApplication(options);
...
}
```

But still not working, Please help me fix it.

Comment: We’re the LoopBack 4 dependencies recently updated? If so, please see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5368#issuecomment-626233755.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Use this code to fix it `const finished = await this.invokeMiddleware(context); if (finished) return;`

Answer (score 0):

If LoopBack 4 was recently updated, then the Sequence must be updated to accept Express.js middleware:

```js
import {inject} from '@loopback/context';
import {
  FindRoute,
  InvokeMethod,
  InvokeMiddleware,
  ParseParams,
  Reject,
  RequestContext,
  RestBindings,
  Send,
  SequenceHandler,
} from '@loopback/rest';

const SequenceActions = RestBindings.SequenceActions;

export class MySequence implements SequenceHandler {
  /**
   * Optional invoker for registered middleware in a chain.
   * To be injected via SequenceActions.INVOKE_MIDDLEWARE.
   */
  @inject(SequenceActions.INVOKE_MIDDLEWARE, {optional: true})
  protected invokeMiddleware: InvokeMiddleware = () => false;

  constructor(
    @inject(SequenceActions.FIND_ROUTE) protected findRoute: FindRoute,
    @inject(SequenceActions.PARSE_PARAMS) protected parseParams: ParseParams,
    @inject(SequenceActions.INVOKE_METHOD) protected invoke: InvokeMethod,
    @inject(SequenceActions.SEND) public send: Send,
    @inject(SequenceActions.REJECT) public reject: Reject,
  ) {}

  async handle(context: RequestContext) {
    try {
      const {request, response} = context;
      const finished = await this.invokeMiddleware(context);
      if (finished) return;
      const route = this.findRoute(request);
      const args = await this.parseParams(request, route);
      const result = await this.invoke(route, args);
      this.send(response, result);
    } catch (err) {
      this.reject(context, err);
    }
  }
}
```

### Further reading

- https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5368#issuecomment-626233755

Answer (score -1):

Using proxy in Angular to bypass CORS problem.

Instead of sending request from browser when you run `ng serve`, you will use proxy. It will intercept your request and sending in local machine (not from your browser).

Check [Angular.io proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)